# Vuejs2 component not updating as parent data changes

Tags: vuejs2

I am trying to make a simple product catalogue using vuejs2.

All my data is stored in an object array, I then have a subset of this data which is what the product catalogue uses to display each product.The subset is used for pagination.

When a user switches pages it clears and pushes the next set of data into the array.

This automatically makes the product component display the new data.

I have issues with the following, each product has multiple colours which are stored as a comma delimited string eg (white, blue, red)

I am trying to make that information appear as a drop down list of options beside each product.

This works until I switch to the next page of data, all other details update except the colour drop downs, which only reflect the previous set of data.

My product list is stored in an object array like:

```
 var obj = {
           productID: productID,
           product: title,
           gender: gender,
           colour: colour,
           cost: cost,
           size: size,
           description: description
          }
  productArray.push(obj);
```

I then have several components that display this array of data:

```
Vue.component('product-list', {
 template: '<ul id="productList">'+
        '<product :productID="product.productID" v-for="product in products">'+
        '<h4>Colour</h4><colourSelect :colours="product.colour" :productID="product.productID"></colourSelect>' +
        '<h4>Gender</h4><span class="genderSpan"><p v-bind:id="getID(product.productID)">{{product.gender}}</p></span>' +

    '</product></ul>',
data: function() {
    return {
        products:
          paginatedArray

    };
},

Vue.component('colourSelect', {
 props: ['productID', 'colours'],
 template: '<select  v-bind:id="getID()" class="form-control input-xs"><colourOption v-for="colourItem in colourArray"></colourOption></select>',
data: function () { //split string based into array
    var newArray = [];
    var optionsArray = this.colours.split(',');


    for (i = 0; i < optionsArray.length; i++) {
        var obj = {
            colour: optionsArray[i]
        }
        newArray.push(obj)
    }
    return {
        colourArray: newArray

    };
},
methods: {
    getID: function (test) {
        return 'colourSelect' + this.productID;
    }
  }
});

Vue.component('colourOption', {
 props:['options'],
 template: '<option><slot></slot></option>'
});
```

Within the app section of vuejs I have the following methods that do the pagination:

```
        buildPages: function () {

        for (i = 1; i < this.listLength() /this.totalPage ; i++) {
            this.pages.push(i);
        }
        var page = this.currentPage * this.totalPage;

        for (i = page; i < page +  this.totalPage ; i++) {
            paginatedArray.push(productArray[i]);
        }


    },
    listLength: function () {
        var listTotal = productArray.length;
        return listTotal
    },
    changePage: function (number) {
        this.currentPage = number
        var page = this.currentPage * this.totalPage;
        //paginatedArray = [];

        var count = 0;
        for (i = page; i < page + this.totalPage ; i++) {
            if (typeof productArray[i] !== 'undefined') {
                paginatedArray.splice(count, 1, productArray[i])
            }

            count++
        }
    },
```

productArray is the main array storing data, paginatedArray is the subset of data that the product component works off.

The issue appears to be within the colourSelect component, within its "data" section it splits the colour data and returns it as an colourOption component into the select, but won't update when the paginatedArray changes.

The colourSelect component does however appear to actually get passed the correct data, as getID method updates correctly. Its just the data section which is not being re-rerun.

This is my first vuejs site, anyone have any ideas around this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make the `colourArray` as a computed property, as the `data` block of component gets executed only once and later change of props will not update  `colourArray` .

```
Vue.component('colourSelect', {
  props: ['productID', 'colours'],
  template: '<select  v-bind:id="getID()" class="form-control input-xs"><colourOption v-for="colourItem in colourArray"></colourOption></select>',
  computed:{
    colourArray: function () { //split string based into array
      var newArray = [];
      var optionsArray = this.colours.split(',');


      for (i = 0; i < optionsArray.length; i++) {
         var obj = {
            colour: optionsArray[i]
        }
        newArray.push(obj)
      }
      return newArray
  }
},
methods: {
    getID: function (test) {
        return 'colourSelect' + this.productID;
    }
  }
});
```